# Persisting HDFS state after EMR cluster is recreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, amazon-emr

Is it possible to persist the state of HDFS storage on a an emr cluster after its recreated? In my experience, all the files stored locally are lost.

Would it be an option to use a mounted volume, say EFS, and mount the EMR cluster to that file mount?
ex:

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///mnt/my/efs/location/</value>
  </property>
```

Looking to find a way to pick off where the cluster last left off if it was deleted. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An EMR cluster uses local stores and mounted EBS of the EC2 instances for HDFS disk areas (you can check the amount of disk space available HDFS are more or less the amount of disks mounted on EMR cluster nodes). As far as I know, using EFS is not an option because the IAM permissions to use EFS and Security Gateway to attach are not options when creating an EMR cluster.

We can use [S3DistCp (s3-dist-cp)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) to copy from HDFS to S3. Or stick to EMRFS instead of HDFS.

Comment: If it were possible to bootstrap the process via terraform, would EMR read from the existing filesystem or attempt to create a new one?

Comment: You can bootstrap from Terraform (aws_emr_cluster resource has bootstrap_action attribute to specify the script to use, which you can upload to S3 and point to S3 from bootstrap_action). I am not sure what "read from existing". Bootstrap is to setup a new EMR cluster, not an existing EMR cluster.

Comment: If you create a new EMR cluster, the file/disk of EC2 instances in the EMR cluster are always new. The previously used localstore or EBS volumes are all gone. You cannot somehow magically recollect them and use them. It is clearly written in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-storage.html. "Amazon EBS volumes attached to EMR clusters are ephemeral: the volumes are deleted upon cluster and instance termination (for example, when shrinking instance groups), so it's important that you not expect data to persist. "

Comment: As clearly told in the document, please give up the expectation that somehow the EBS or Localstore attached to your EMR cluster can get saved or re-used.

Comment: The document says "EMRFS can help ensure that there is a persistent "source of truth" for HDFS data stored in Amazon S3.". Which means you cannot expect to keep HDFS contents once your EMR cluster is gone.